Does operator < need to be declared before calling std::lexicographical_compare
The following code compiles before C++20:
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
};

struct FooArray
{
    std::vector<Foo> a;
};

bool operator<(const FooArray& a, const FooArray& b)
{
    return std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(a.a), std::end(a.a), std::begin(b.a), std::end(b.a));
}

bool operator<(const Foo& a, const Foo& b)
{
    return false;
}

With c++20 enabled GCC 10 and 11 reject the code, but only when optimisations are enabled:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/algorithm:61,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter::operator()(_Iterator1, _Iterator2) const [with _Iterator1 = const Foo*; _Iterator2 = const Foo*]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:1240:14:   required from 'constexpr bool std::__lexicographical_compare_impl(_II1, _II1, _II2, _II2, _Compare) [with _II1 = const Foo*; _II2 = const Foo*; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:1257:46:   required from 'static constexpr bool std::__lexicographical_compare<_BoolType>::__lc(_II1, _II1, _II2, _II2) [with _II1 = const Foo*; _II2 = const Foo*; bool _BoolType = false]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:1302:60:   required from 'constexpr bool std::__lexicographical_compare_aux(_II1, _II1, _II2, _II2) [with _II1 = const Foo*; _II2 = const Foo*]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:1605:48:   required from 'constexpr bool std::lexicographical_compare(_II1, _II1, _II2, _II2) [with _II1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Foo*, std::vector<Foo> >; _II2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Foo*, std::vector<Foo> >]'
<source>:15:40:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:43:23: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const Foo' and 'const Foo')
   43 |       { return *__it1 < *__it2; }
      |                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/algorithm:61,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1097:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR, class _Container> constexpr std::__detail::__synth3way_t<_IteratorR, _IteratorL> __gnu_cxx::operator<=>(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)' (reversed)
 1097 |     operator<=>(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1097:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/algorithm:61,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:43:23: note:   'const Foo' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>'
   43 |       { return *__it1 < *__it2; }
      |                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/algorithm:61,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1114:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Iterator, class _Container> constexpr std::__detail::__synth3way_t<_T1> __gnu_cxx::operator<=>(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)' (rewritten)
 1114 |     operator<=>(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1114:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/algorithm:61,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:43:23: note:   'const Foo' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>'
   43 |       { return *__it1 < *__it2; }
      |                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
<source>:13:6: note: candidate: 'bool operator<(const FooArray&, const FooArray&)'
   13 | bool operator<(const FooArray& a, const FooArray& b)
      |      ^~~~~~~~
<source>:13:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const Foo' to 'const FooArray&'
   13 | bool operator<(const FooArray& a, const FooArray& b)
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
Compiler returned: 1

GCC 12 and later compile the code. MSVC always compiles the code, clang rejects it when c++20 is enabled.
https://godbolt.org/z/9ra6hn7c9
Which compiler is correct? Does bool operator<(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) need to be declared before calling std::lexicographical_compare? Is this a change in c++20 or did the code just happen to work in c++17 (I was surprised the code wasn't causing problems in c++17 too)?

I think it is related to the end of file is also considered an instantiation point issue.

GCC and MSVC seem to delay the actual instantiation until the end where the declaration of operator< is available. But clang tries does the instantiation. I maybe wrong here though.

This answer should explain the issue. Can the point of instantiation be delayed until the end of the translation unit?

If the order of declaration is exactly so but definitions are done separately, it compiles so I think so.

@user12002570 that question would indicate that the code should be valid, it therefore doesn't explain why it doesn't compile with clang when c++20 is enabled.

@AlanBirtles Once you get what is the standard conformant behavior, your question is answered. Whether a compiler is implementing it correctly or showing regression is another matter.

The answer is it depends on implementation of lexicographical_compare. If it doesn't require instantiation in function bool operator<(const FooArray& a, const FooArray& b) then it should work as expected on all compilers. If implementation requires instantiation (clang) then it should fail to compile.

This is ill-formed no diagnostic required as  per temp.param#7. Note also that std::lexicographical_compare is constexpr from C++20 and also the related issue in CWG2497.
First note that there are two point of instantiations(POI). The first POI is at namespace scope just after operator<(const FooArray& a, const FooArray& b) as per temp.point:

For a function template specialization, a member function template specialization, or a specialization for a member function or static data member of a class template, if the specialization is implicitly instantiated because it is referenced from within another template specialization and the context from which it is referenced depends on a template parameter, the point of instantiation of the specialization is the point of instantiation of the enclosing specialization.
Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a specialization immediately follows the namespace scope declaration or definition that refers to the specialization.

The second POI is at the end of the translation unit.
Now as per temp.point#7:

A specialization for a class template has at most one point of instantiation within a translation unit.
A specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation units. If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

This means that the given program is IFNDR because it violates basic.def.odr:

In each such definition, the overloaded operators referred to, the implicit calls to conversion functions, constructors, operator new functions and operator delete functions, shall refer to the same function.

The above is violated because at the first POI, there is no operator< that we can refer to but at the second POI there is. So they don't refer to the same function.

The solution is to provide a declaration before first POI so that the referred to functions are the samea at both the POIs.

I don't think this is correct. The function bool operator<(const FooArray& a, const FooArray& b) doesn't require template instantiation until it's used. It wouldn't compile if it were to instantiate it. Clang has a different implementation, forcing instantiation and so it failed to compile. Otherwise it should compile on every modern compiler and produce the same result. See: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jzh3zExGc

@Gene bool operator<(const FooArray& a, const FooArray& b) isn't a tempate so instantiate doesn't actually applicable to it. You probably meant std::lexicographical_compare. Also note that even if we use FooArray etc then also clang rejects it. Demo. It's also implementation dependent but still IFNDR afaik.

as I said, clang uses a different implementation and instantiates template in operator<. In general case the instantiation of template isn't required. Bottom line, depending on lexicographical_compare implementation compiler either fails trying to instantiate it, or it doesn't instantiate it and then everything works as expected. It's implementation dependent, but there is no UB.

@Gene IFNDR is not UB btw.

you are wrong, there is no UB, and it's not ill-formed

@Gene I never said it is UB in my answer anywhere. UB and IFNDR are two different things.

your answer even theoretically couldn't be correct, because compiler wouldn't be able to instantiate lexicographical_compare if there is no operator<. And every compiler shows that it defers instantiation after the operator is defined.

@Gene It's not about what the compiler is able to do or not. It's about what the standard says.

and that's exactly what the Standard says. See correct answer below.

@Gene Read carefully your answer, the standard doesn't say it is implementation-specific.

when it depends on implementation of the standard library lexicographical_compare -- it is implementation specific

@Gene That is not what implentation-specific means in c++. Looks like you don't know the difference between IFNDR, UB and implementation-specific. Everything in/of the standard library function template depends on implementation, so as per you logic everthing is implementatino-specific.

"implementation-specific" not explicitly defined as a formal term in the Standard, "implementation-specific" generally refers to behavior or features that are unique to a particular implementation and not covered by the Standard.

@Gene Also you've failed to show why the quoted reference in my answer are not applicable. If they are applicable(which is the case here) then this is IFNDR as explicitly mentioned by the standard. I'll updated/delete the answer if there's technically wrong.

your quotes are not relevant, there can't be ODR violation no matter what. If compiler instantiates immediately, it's a compilation error, because there is no operator<. If compiler delays instantiation, everything works, because it sees operator<. Either one or the other.

@Gene You do know that in most cases ODR violation are IFNDR, right? Also, you're thinking from compiler's POV instead of what the standard says. I am saying that in your answer you're ignoring the part that is mentioned in my answer that make is IFNDR. There is implicit instantiation no doubt, but POI still have to be taken into account which is done by the mentioned references in my answer.

@Gene ""implementation-specific" not explicitly defined as a formal term in the Standard..." No, the standard does define the term "implementation-defined". It has a precise meaning in the c++ standard.

where in the Standard "implementation-specific" is formally defined?

@Gene There is no such things as "implementation-specific" in the standard. You shouldn't invent your own terminilogy. C++ is hard enough with the already present terms. Adding these more terms is even more confusing. Also this is related to CWG2497 and the two POI issue as already explained in my answer. Note also that std::lexicographical_compare is constexpr since C++20..

why, just search the Standard, you'll find many times it uses "implementation-specific" exactly the same way I described.

@Gene Yes, as I see now it is indeed used in the standard but note defined anywhere. I'll submit/create a CWG issue for it shortly.
